# Use of "much" in sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, passive-voice

I know that we use **much** in questions and negative clauses. If so, is this sentence correct ? I can't see neither negative nor question in this sentence .

> "Despite the fact that Senegal has had much importance in African
>   politics since its independence,it's strategic position has been of no
>   significance"

Comment: *Senegal has had much importance in African politics* is "valid", but I don't find it very idiomatic. Much more natural is *Senegal has **been very important** in African politics*. The same applies to *has had much **influence***, which might be better expressed as *has been very **influential***.

Answer (score 2):

It's technically OK to use *much* like your example, but as @FumbleFingers says, it's not very idiomatic and sounds slightly odd.

*Much X* means there is a large amount of X and X is something uncountable (if it's countable you would use *many*).

When not used in a negative expression you can say *so much*.

> "Despite the fact that Senegal has had so much importance in African politics since its independence,it's strategic position has been of no significance"